# How to create Objective-C Protocol in new version of XCode Version 6.0.1 (6A317) for iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, protocols

In previous versions when you press New File, in iOS --> Cocoa Touch --> there was Objective-C protocol, but now I can't find it there!?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Familiar problem after update.

Step one: press CMD+N and choose Objective-C File in menu

[image]

Step two: press Next and choose file type.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add File -> Source -> Objective-C File -> [Now there's a combo for file type, select Protocol in there]