# xCode6 iOS8 how to create a file with an extension for an existing class?

Tags: objective-c, templates, ios8, xcode6, class-extensions

if I remember correctly, in xCode 5 and below, the "New File" option for project navigator included a template to create an extension for an existing class. This option was next to "Cocoa Touch Class" and allowed to enter a base class name. The generated file had a form like "NSString+JSON.h"

**How do I create class extensions in xCode 6? Do I start with a class file and then modify it and it's name to include category name?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is similar to this question I answered:

[How to create Objective-C Protocol in new version of XCode Version 6.0.1 (6A317) for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320629/how-to-create-objective-c-protocol-in-new-version-of-xcode-version-6-0-1-6a317/26320789#26320789)

**Select New File > Objective-C File > Choose Extension from the dropdown.**
[image]